# how to coalesce a sql stored procedures parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure parameter `organisationID` which use to filter my queries by:

```
where pr.ProfileID = @profileID
and oi.OrganisationID = @organisationID
```

I would like to coalesce it so that if null is passed in then the query is not filtered by it.

Answer (score 4):

A typical way to do this is:

```
where (@profileID is null or pr.ProfileID = @profileID) and
      (@organisationID is null or oi.OrganisationID = @organisationID)
```

Comment: Do note though that is you have a lot of these, you are often better off performance-wise using dynamic SQl to generate the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
where pr.ProfileID = @profileID
and oi.OrganisationID = isnull(@organisationID, oi.OrganisationID)
```

This assumes you're only filtering on the one value, the logic could be applied to both parameters.

Comment: Pretty much the same logic as @Gordon's, but I find the isnull format easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
where pr.ProfileID = COALESCE(@profileID, pr.ProfileID)
and oi.OrganisationID = COALESCE(@organisationID,oi.OrganisationID)
```